# Make child object be always on top

Tags: qt, qml

I was wondering either the following functionality is available in QML: I need for a child object (a text here) to always stay on top of other object, no matter the child/ parent connection. Here is a MWE:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectMain;

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "white"

        Rectangle
        {
            id: rect1;

            width: 200;
            height: 200;

            x: 100;
            y: 100;

            color: "red";

            Text
            {
                id: theText;
                text: qsTr("text");

                anchors.centerIn: parent;
            }
        }

        Rectangle
        {
            id: rect2;

            width: 200;
            height: 200;

            x: 200;
            y: 200;

            color: "yellow";
        }
    }
}
```

It will show this window:

[image]

As you can see the "text" is covered with `rec2`, as it's a child of `rect1`, which was created prior to `rect2`. Is it possible for the text to be always on top of `rect2` with current parent/ child connection?

Comment: Is it necessary that the text be a child of rect1 ?, if so, why?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, it is. In the full code, now MWE, the rectangles are being created as a list view. They overlay each other a bit, and each one has this text property, which is covered by the next rectangle. It would be useful to be able to make the text property's always on top.

Comment: I think that what you want is impossible, so my idea is to give you another approach to obtain the same result, so I asked you. Why is it necessary for the text to be the child of rect1?

Comment: Architecture wise, I think this is a good approach, since each text property really belongs to rect1, rect2 and so on. If this is not possible, I would probably need to create a shadow list with only text's that would be placed on the rectangles after they are created.

Comment: Well, for me the property that should do that job is the  `z` property: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop  , but I have tried it and it does not work if there is no direct relationship.

Comment: You must proceed from the given. The `z` property works for siblings only. So you have to put your text or item contains the text as sibling to rect or to rects. this is what is. The specific implementation, of course, can be done in different ways

Comment: Too bad, I will need to figure out an another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the idea I expressed above. But I really can imagine for myself how that could be used. If you could define your real goals we will find another solution, of course.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true
    title: "Example"

    Item {
        z: 1
        Repeater {
            id: rectGenerator
            property bool loaded: false
            Component.onCompleted: rectGenerator.loaded = true
            model: 10
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),0.8)
                x: Math.round(Math.random() * 300)
                y: Math.round(Math.random() * 300)
                Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
                MouseArea {
                    id: dragArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Loader {
        z: 2
        sourceComponent: Repeater {
            model: rectGenerator.model
            delegate: Text {
                x: rectGenerator.itemAt(index).x
                y: rectGenerator.itemAt(index).y
                width: 100
                height: 100
                text: "item " + (index + 1)
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter                    
            }
        }
        active: rectGenerator.loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually your example pretty much represents my problem. I think this would complicate my cod e abit just for this text functionality but I see it works. Could you please explain a bit more what is the general idea here? Why does loading order matter?

Comment: That done to be ensure the order of creation. The Loader's layer must be created after `Item`'s layer already exists. But this is just an illustration of the idea and should not be used in a real application.

Comment: Well, even though being only an ilustration of the concept, I see no other real way of doing it. I am creating X amount of objects, just like you, that can overlay each other, but their text property has to always be on top.